# How to copy a branch into another in Git

Tags: git, github

So I have a github repo which only had 1 brach (master) where I was doing all my work. It was all the files for a website. Now I have activated github pages for it which created another branch with some files which came in it by default. How can I copy all my files (from master branch) for my website and put it into the github-pages branch? That way I can push changes and view it live on the github page online. I'm new to git and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

When Github auto-creates your gh-pages branch it makes it an orphan branch (it has no commit history on it). If you want to make your github pages branch mirror your master branch then probably the easiest way would be to delete the current gh-pages branch, re-branch it from master and then push it up. Something like this should work:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D gh-pages
git checkout -b gh-pages
git push origin gh-pages -f
```

These all assume that you're in a local clone of your repo and that the Github repo is set to a remote named origin.

**Be aware though that the above commands are deleting whatever you have currently in your gh-pages branch.**